# How to center menu items

Tags: css

I need to center the block (the one with red background) that contains all menu items inside the screen.

To better understand, please take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dforce/mf9h78vn/3/

The css instruction:

```
margin:auto;
```

Seems not working.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way then, and tell us if it's what you wanted :)

```
ul.main-menu {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is an very good tutorial for an alternative solution: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hello and thank you for your kind suggestions!
It seems the menu now is centered:

http://www.piedicosta.com/joomla3/it

There is only one problem:

If you shrink the browser window until the menu becomes responsive and you click to open a submenu, if you enlarge again the window of the browser you will see the menu aligned to the left.

Why?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think it's because you set a 'width: 100%;' somewhere :/

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with this menu https://jsfiddle.net/dforce/mf9h78vn/15/

Once this menu is displayed on resolution higher than 979px it look centered, than if I shrink the browser window an I click on a menu item, when I enlarge again the menu, it looses the alignment at center and it goes aligned left.

How is this possible?

I have tried to use the instruction:

```
display:inline-block
```

You can see an example here: http://www.piedicosta.com/joomla3/it/